# Node.JS return out of callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, return-value, node-modules

I am using this plugin manager https://github.com/c9/architect and creating a node module. The problem I am having is that I want to expose an api from my node module to the host application. The problem is that the plugin manager uses callbacks to signal that all plugins have been registered.

Example:
In my main app, I require my api module that I am creating

```
var api = require('apiModule')
```

And in my node_modules directory

```
module.exports = (function apiModule(){

    architect.createApp(config, function(err, app){
        if(err) throw err;

        return app

    });

})();
```

This obviously does not work, but shows that I am trying to return the value of `app` to the main application.

How can I get the value of `app` back to the `api` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing in a callback, but creating one. 
You're function shouldn't execute itself either.

Your code should be:

```
var architect = require('architect');
module.exports = function apiModule(config, callback){

    architect.createApp(config, callback);

});

//otherModule
var apiModule = require('apiModule');
var config = require('config');
apiModule(config, function(err, app){
    if(err) throw err;

    // do something with app
});
```

If you're looking for a more idiomatic api to what you're used to. 
I suggest you try [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

```
var architect = require('architect');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var createApp = Promise.promisify(architect.createApp);
module.exports = function apiModule(config) {
    return createApp(config);
}

// Then in your other module
var apiModule = require('apiModule');
apiModule()
    .then(function(result) {})
    .catch(function(error) {})
```

I hope that clears it up :)

Comment: The function in the first module will be executed immediately when you `require('apiModule')` and fails cause `callback` won't be defined. You have to remove the `()`

Comment: You were quite quick to minus the answer, but too lazy to provide a solution. Great manners.

Comment: See my comments in the above answer. I can t have the users who download my module be require to wrap their application with my callback function

Comment: Okay, so that's not how it works in the async world of node. 
Your users still have to pass in a callback if they're working with your lib and it's executing an async function, else they'll just never get the result.

Comment: I looked further into this and realized this is no different than a standard callback. The solution I need is to be able to turn this async module loader into a sync process or as close to as possible. I cannot ask users to write all their code inside a callback function.

Comment: well, make your module an eventemitter and emit a 'ready' event when it's done, outside your code require('module') then module.on('ready', yourusershandlerfunction) no callback involved from the user's side.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a callback to your your module :

```
module.exports = function(callback){

    architect.createApp(config, function(err, app){
        if(err) throw err;

        return callback(app); //you should check if callback is a function to prevent error

    });

});

var api = require('apiModule');
api(function(app) {
    console.log(app); //you access your app

})
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but you have to remember that I will be providing this module to others. I cant have them wrap their whole application in my callback. I need them to be able to just `require()` and be able to use it. Even if they had to do a second step, maybe shared variable that will become available or something.